# Comment Shorthand Links Too Deeplinked

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown

Re: this help resource:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

These shorthand links are incredibly useful, but the page is nearly impossible to find.:

Help -> Our Model -> How do I Format My Posts Using Markdown or HTML? -> Advanced Editing Page link -> Comment Formatting

Can we please un-deeplink this valuable information? The shorthand links for about/help for use in linking users to information about what questions to ask and how is almost a necessity on a daily basis.

Comment: Tangentially related, we could create a [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122) here too.